# "Shortcuts Events.app" keeps taking windows focus, but I'm not using Shortcuts

Tags: macos, applications, window-manager, shortcuts-app

Every few minutes the application window I'm working in loses focus.

With [these troubleshooting tips](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123730/is-there-a-way-to-detect-what-program-is-stealing-focus-on-my-mac) I found out it's caused by the macOS Shortcuts.app.
Apparently, the following app gains focus: `Shortcuts Events [/System/Applications/Shortcuts.app/Contents/Library/Helpers/Shortcuts Events.app`

This is quite annoying, especially since I'm not currently using Shortcuts for anything.

So if anyone knows of a way to either

- avoid this behavior or
- remove the Shortcuts app and its helper from the system entirely

I would be really grateful.

Comment: if you think this is a bug, report to https://apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macOS 12.3 update that was just released seems to have fixed the issue.

I was having exactly the same issue.

I did some test and find out whenever I launch `BetterTouchTool`, `Shortcuts Events.app` will also run.

After the OS update, `Shortcuts Events.app` no longer runs at BTT launch.

I've also used the [python code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123730/is-there-a-way-to-detect-what-program-is-stealing-focus-on-my-mac) to monitor app switches. `Shortcuts Events.app` used to randomly run and steal window focus; it did it from once per hour to once per two hours. After the OS update, I've been monitoring app switch for more than 4 hours, and `Shortcuts Events.app` never shows up again.

Please upgrade your macOS to 12.3 to see if your problem has been fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/319863)

Comment: Hi @agarza, I've confirmed that the macOS 12.3 update has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Shortcuts App is a new addition to MacOS / iOS enabling programmable interactions with your device. If it is stealing focus, it sounds like you have some shortcut configured, possibly on a timed interval.

Easiest thing to do would be open the Mac shortcuts app, go to all shortcuts, and try and delete or disable shortcuts until this loss of focus stops happening.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for taking the time to respond. There are no shortcuts configured at a timed interval. Deleting all shortcuts could possibly help, though I would like to keep a few in case I do need them at some point. Deleting the entire Shortcuts app is not possible on macOS.

Comment: Hi @JonasW you're right you can't delete builtin apps like shortcuts in the way I described. Are the only shortcuts you have the app the defaults? If so there should be no harm in deleting them, but its also hard to imagine those causing your issue