# All windows loses focus every 5 minutes

Tags: macos

While in Chrome or Sublime Text and mail for sure, my window will lose focus on 5 minute intervals. How do I determine culprit so that I can eliminate it? I've tried a reboot and closing applications that I think might be responsible and can't figure out what's actually causing the problem.

Comment: look in your Console for repeating event.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139607/22003
If you need help to make `lastcomm` usable, just ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following Python script which can tell you which app is currently on focus:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Prints current window focus.
# See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/169277
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
import time
workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
active_app = workspace.activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']
print('Active focus: ' + active_app)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    prev_app = active_app
    active_app = workspace.activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']
    if prev_app != active_app:
        print('Focus changed to: ' + active_app)
```

It will print active application which has the focus and any change every second.

<sup>Related script: [Identify which app or process is stealing focus on OSX](https://gist.github.com/iMerica/8928556) at Gist</sup>

Usage:

1. Save above script into [`get_active_focus.py` file](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/scripts/python/AppKit/get_active_focus.py).
2. Assign execution attributes by: `chmod +x get_active_focus.py` command.
3. Run it as: `./get_active_focus.py`.

Output:

```
$ ./get_active_focus.py
Active focus: Terminal
Focus changed to: Google Chrome
```

---

Once you found the affected application, consider uninstalling or killing it (if possible).

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks so much. Note that you can skip setting execute permissions by directly running `python get_active_focus.py`